# NN training - using one hot encoding vs having artificial features

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I am trying to use a NN for regression - my setup has 2 hidden layers.

The input data i have is of the following structure - features A,B,C,D are numerical (can take up values from -500k to 500k), feature E is categorical and F is the dependent variable I am trying to predict. A,B,C,D will vary per country (hence why I have included country as a separate feature).

I have tried two different approaches to express feature E when training:

1. One hot encoding
2. Using the existing A,B,C,D features

I have attached a screenshot of what the training data looks like (made up values) as well as my two approaches.

```
[data][1]
[Option1][2]
[Option2][3]
```

Option (2) works very well (in terms of r^2 and accuracy for the individual predictions), whereas (1) works pretty badly.

I also tried normalizing A,B,C,D (-mean/std) when using one-hot-encoding but it didn't help much.

Worth noting - Option (2) works very well even *without* normalization.

My question is - how can I understand why this is the case? I would think one hot encoding should work just fine, but it seems like it doesn't. Why does the NN understand the classification better from approach (2)?

Thanks

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sixHw.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMw8O.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eQxk.png
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried normalizing A,B,C,D when using one-hot-encoding but it didn't help much.

I suggest you test this further. This would be the best thing to do. Because neural networks will approximate a function better if the data is in the range of `0` to `1` as this fits well with the activation functions.

But you always have to normalize all data *equally*. To normalize a number, e.g. A=346, you have to divide it by a number that is 346 or higher, *but also higher than all values for A in the dataset*.

And if A,B,C,D are similar characteristics, you can normalize them all the same. If they are completely different characteristics, do the same as below for EVERY characteristic (A, B, C and D).

So for the following dataset:

```
{ A: 212, B: 1241, C: 321, D: 2, country: Germany }
{ A: 72, B: 412, C: 545, D: 345, country: UK}
{ A: 43, B: 123, C: 4, D: 977, country: Netherlands}
```

You have to divide A,B,C and D by the same number to normalize them. The countries should be one-hot encoded, like you already did.

So the highest value for A,B,C,D is 1241, so I will divide all numbers by this value:

```
{ A: 0.17, B: 1, C: 0.26, D: 0, DE: 1, UK: 0, NL: 0 }
{ A: 0.06, B: 0.33, C: 0.44, D: 0.28, DE: 0, UK: 1, NL: 0 }
{ A: 0.03, B: 0.10, C: 0, D: 0.79, DE: 0, UK: 0, NL: 1}
```

*numbers are rounded*

More info [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/wiki/Normalization-101)

Comment: Hmm, I did use the StandardScaler from sklearn - it subtracts the mean and divides by the stdev for each feature (so, column-wise) - do you think this is not enough?